# lua string printing

Tags: lua, format-string

In C, I have format strings, something like:

```
char *msg = "wlll you marry me"
fprintf(stderr, "%s, %s?", name, msg);
```

Now, can I do something similar in lua with format strings? I.e. I want something functionally equivalent to:

```
name .. ", " .. msg .. "?"
```

but not so ugly, in lua.

Okay, so I can do string.format("%s, %s?", name, msg), but can I go even a step further, something like perl style, where I can go:

```
"%name, %msg?"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Lua Users Wiki article on String Interpolation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringInterpolation), Lua does not offer a built-in native way to do this; however, there are a couple sort-of workarounds posted on that page.

> Here's one simple implementation (-- RiciLake):
>
> ```
> function interp(s, tab)
>   return (s:gsub('($%b{})', function(w) return tab[w:sub(3, -2)] or w end))
> end
> print( interp("${name} is ${value}", {name = "foo", value = "bar"}) )
>
> getmetatable("").__mod = interp
> print( "${name} is ${value}" % {name = "foo", value = "bar"} )
> -- Outputs "foo is bar"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

> Can I do something similar [to printf] with Lua format strings?

**Yes.** I do this all the time:

```
local function printf(...) return io.stdout:write(string.format(...)) end

local function fprintf(f, ...) return f:write(string.format(...)) end
```

Modify to taste.